# Were there originally 64 Jyotirlingas in the world?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga, linga-purana

Is it true that it is mentioned in the Linga Puranas, that originally there were 64 Jyotirlingas in the world?  If yes, then in which chapter is it mentioned? Can anyone please enlighten me on this.